# I don't have permission to insert a web parts in content editor(Enterprise page)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I try to put a two web parts side by side in sharepoint 2013 by using content editor,but web part icon is disabled in content editor.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I actually have understand the question. You want to add two web parts inside another content editor web part? Anyway, any specific reason you couldn't simply use a two column web part page layout instead?